# why Thread.VolatileRead on string doesn't compile

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

```
class CFoo 
{
       private string _filePathFormatString;

       public string Foo()
       {
            System.Threading.Thread.VolatileRead(ref _filePathFormatString);
            ...
       }   
}
```

string is object, why this `VolatileRead` doesn't compile? 
I think it should match `VolatileRead(ref object)` signature.

Comment: why are you using VolatileRead? the msdn says "Under normal circumstances, the C# lock statement [...] provide easier alternatives". or why don't you just define the variable as volatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types of formal and actual parameters must be exactly the same if you pass parameter with "ref" in C#. So you can change field to be type of object. Second way to do it might be using [ReaderWriteLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) instead of volatile read.